# Assigning elements in an array into the same DataFrame using scala ad spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I input an array and then I want to get their unicodes and store into a dataframe. Here is my code

```
def getUnicodeOfEmoji (emojiArray : Array[String]) : DataFrame = {
    val existingSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import existingSparkSession.implicits._
    var result: DataFrame = null
    var df : DataFrame = null
    for (i <- 0 until emojiArray.length) {
      
      df = Seq(emojiArray(i)).toDF("emoji")
      
      df.show()
      
      result = df.selectExpr(
        "emoji",
        "'U+' || trim('0' , string(hex(encode(emoji, 'utf-32')))) as result"
      )
      
    }
    result.show(false)
    return result
  }

}

input = val emojis=""
```

actual output

```
|emoji|result |
+-----+-------+
|   |U+1F60D|
+-----+-------+
```

But I need to have all 3 emojis with their specific unicodes within the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop to construct the dataframe. You can convert the array to a `Seq` and use the `toDF` method of a `Seq` to construct the resulting dataframe.

```
def getUnicodeOfEmoji (emojiArray : Array[String]) : DataFrame = {
    val existingSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import existingSparkSession.implicits._
    val df = emojiArray.toSeq.toDF("emoji")
    val result = df.selectExpr(
        "emoji",
        "'U+' || trim('0' , string(hex(encode(emoji, 'utf-32')))) as result"
    )
    result.show(false)
    return result
  }

val emojis = ""
val input = raw"\p{block=Emoticons}".r.findAllIn(emojis).toArray
val converted = getUnicodeOfEmoji(input)
+-----+-------+
|emoji|result |
+-----+-------+
|   |U+1F603|
|   |U+1F61C|
|   |U+1F60D|
+-----+-------+
```

A slight improvement is to convert your string of emojis to a `Seq[String]` directly before feeding into the function, e.g.

```
def getUnicodeOfEmoji (emojiArray : Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
    val existingSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import existingSparkSession.implicits._
    val df = emojiArray.toDF("emoji")
    val result = df.selectExpr(
        "emoji",
        "'U+' || trim('0' , string(hex(encode(emoji, 'utf-32')))) as result"
    )
    result.show(false)
    return result
  }

val emojis = ""
val input = raw"\p{block=Emoticons}".r.findAllIn(emojis).toSeq
val converted = getUnicodeOfEmoji(input)
```